# How to Prevent long text label wrapping under the checkbox/radio button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Sample Markup and CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lktm0L6/1/)

```css
.wrap {
  width: 220px;
}

.indi-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.control-label {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 300;
}

button.btn-link {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
  </div>
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">Xonsectetur adipiscing.</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
  </div>
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:**
I know i can just wrap the checkbox inside the label to fix that but starting from the "indi-wrap" class its auto populated inside the parent "wrap" therefor I can't edit anything inside the "indi-wrap".

Is there any way to align the second line of the text label on it's first line? Preventing it wrapping under the checkbox.

Comment: uhh what? where is your code? what second line?

Comment: Edited, so sorry about that i'm new here

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076890/indenting-multiline-labels

Comment: yes, but the thing is I can't edit anything inside the "indi-wrap" class plus i have 3 element inside it, the input, the label and the button. The label and the button is inline with each other and the checkbox should not be.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Prevent wrapping of text below radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472949/prevent-wrapping-of-text-below-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping the existing markup, one simple way to achieve something close is using `inline-block` on the 3 children of `.indi-wrap`, and a `max-width` to fit them all in a single line.

```
.indi-wrap > * {
    display: inline-block !important;
    max-width: 70%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 220px;
}

.indi-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.indi-wrap > * {
    display: inline-block !important;
    max-width: 70%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.control-label {
  font-weight: 300;
}

button.btn-link {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
  </div>
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">Xonsectetur adipiscing.</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
  </div>
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use flexbox to achieve this.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 220px;
}

.indi-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.indi-wrap input { flex: 1; }
.indi-wrap label { flex: 7; }

.control-label {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 300;
}

button.btn-link {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
  </div>
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">Xonsectetur adipiscing.</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
  </div>
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to put both inputs and buttons inside label and then use `display:block` for the label and also positive and negative margins, like this

```css
.wrap {
  width: 220px;
}

.indi-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

label.control-label {
  display:block;
  font-weight: 300;  
    margin-left: 20px;
}
input{  
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px !important;
}

button.btn-link {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <label class="control-label">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <label class="control-label">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      Xonsectetur adipiscing.
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <label class="control-label">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so sorry again, I should have said the "I can't edit anything inside the "indi-wrap""

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```css
.wrap {
  width: 220px;
}

.indi-wrap {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.indi-wrap input[type='checkbox'] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.control-label {
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block
}

button.btn-link {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
  </div>
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">Xonsectetur adipiscing.</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
  </div>
  <div class="indi-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">only</button>
  </div>
</div>
```